# ¿Como puedo evitar crear un objeto repetido en la tableview?

Tags: javafx, oracle-11g

Estoy tratando de hacer una app, con bsdd y javaFX, pero esta me crea el objeto con el LIB_ISBN repetido, pero a la hora de hacer la consulta no lo inserta en la bsdd, por que este ya tiene la primary key asignada, ¿ como puedo evitar que cree el objeto repetido en la tableview ?

Gracias de antemano...!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   private void handleAñadir(ActionEvent event) { 

    Libro lib1 = new Libro(tfISBN.getText(), tfTitulo.getText(), tfAutor.getText(), tfGenero.getText());

    items.add(lib1);

    try {
        Connection con = dbConexion.getConnection();

        String queryI = "INSERT INTO LIBROS(LIB_ISBN,LIB_TITULO,LIB_AUTOR,LIB_GENERO) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmtI = con.prepareStatement(queryI);
        preparedStmtI.setString(1, tfISBN.getText());
        preparedStmtI.setString(2, tfTitulo.getText());
        preparedStmtI.setString(3, tfAutor.getText());
        preparedStmtI.setString(4, tfGenero.getText());
        preparedStmtI.execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta ya preparada anteriormente.
        //System.out.println(queryI);//Mostramos el valor de la consulta insertada.
        System.out.println("Consulta realizada con éxito");
        //se deja la conexion abierta para poder insertar datos nuevos cada vez que quiera...

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setContentText("El isbn ya existe en la bsdd"+"\n"+e.getMessage());
        alert.show();
    }

    btnModificar.setDisable(false);
    btnEliminar.setDisable(false);

    tfISBN.setText("");
    tfTitulo.setText("");
    tfAutor.setText("");
    tfGenero.setText("");
}
```

Comment: El método que uses para introducir un objeto a la tabla, ponlo tras el preparedStmtI.execute(); ya que si falla esa parte, saltara al catch y no introducirá nada a la tabla.

Comment: Gracias ya lo resolví añado el codigo ordenado, lo tenia al reves Valentín.

Answer (score 1):

```
intro@FXML
private void handleAñadir(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Connection con = dbConexion.getConnection();
        String queryI = "INSERT INTO LIBROS(LIB_ISBN,LIB_TITULO,LIB_AUTOR,LIB_GENERO) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmtI = con.prepareStatement(queryI);
        preparedStmtI.setString(1, tfISBN.getText());
        preparedStmtI.setString(2, tfTitulo.getText());
        preparedStmtI.setString(3, tfAutor.getText());
        preparedStmtI.setString(4, tfGenero.getText());
        preparedStmtI.execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta ya preparada anteriormente.
        Libro lib1 = new Libro(tfISBN.getText(), tfTitulo.getText(), tfAutor.getText(), tfGenero.getText());
        items.add(lib1);
        //System.out.println(queryI);//Mostramos el valor de la consulta insertada.
        System.out.println("Consulta realizada con éxito");
        //se deja la conexion abierta para poder insertar datos nuevos cada vez que quiera...
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setContentText("El isbn ya existe en la bsdd" + "\n" + e.getMessage());
        alert.show();
    }

    btnModificar.setDisable(false);
    btnEliminar.setDisable(false);

    tfISBN.setText("");
    tfTitulo.setText("");
    tfAutor.setText("");
    tfGenero.setText("");
}
```